# Почему же ДебЕт, но ДебИторская задолженность?

Tags: словообразование, орфография

Доброго времени дня, уважаемые участники!
Меня, как бухгалтера, заинтересовал такой вопрос: почему отдельно-взятое слово пишется через Е - Дебет, а вот глагол от данного слова- через И - Дебиторская задолженность?

Comment: Простите! Не глагол, а прилагательное. Но если уж говорить про глагол, то здесь снова - буква Е- дебетовать(-ться).

Answer (score 2):

Правильно вы про глагол сказали. ;)
Дебиторская - от дебитор, **дебитовать** (sic!).
http://sis.slovarnik.ru/html/d/debitovat5.html
(**Дебетовать** - это уже позднейшее переосмысление).

Здесь другой суффикс в языках-источниках (латинском, итальянском и французском). Вообще проверка безударных методом поиска "проверочных" однокоренных слов часто не проходит для заимствованных слов. В русском обычно не выделяют иностранные суффиксы, и это приводит к недоразумениям.